# URIで使われるfile://について検索するにはどういうワードを使えば良いですか？

Tags: network, url

URI で使われる `file://` 関係の情報について詳しく調べたいのですが、Google で「file://」を検索ワードにしても単なる「ファイル」の情報ばかり出てきてしまいます。

例：「file:// 実行可能ファイル」で調べても、単に実行可能ファイルの情報が出てきてしまう。

どのような検索ワードで調べれば的確な情報に辿り着きやすいですか？

なお、`file://` という書き方の意味を知りたいのではありません。これが `https://` などの仲間であることは知っています。

Comment: 調べるにあたって何か利用目的などはございますでしょうか？（Aタグで利用するなど。的確なヒントでなく申し訳ないです。）

Comment: @wakuwaku さん、この質問に至った際は、fileスキームでローカルのファイルを開くときに各種ブラウザがかけている制限を知りたかったり、実行可能ファイルを指定したときにオプションまで付けれるのか知りたかったりしました。いちおう質問としては一般的に「fileスキームのほにゃららについて調べたいんだけどひっかからない」という状況を想定しています。

Comment: 今になって質問を見返してみると、「`file://`自体が何か分からなくて検索している」という風にも捉えられる書き方をしてしまっていましたね……。私の意図としては「fileスキームについて詳しく検索したいのだけど難しい」という趣旨でした。

Comment: 「スキーム」という単語を知っているなら、タイトルか本文に含めておいた方が誤解が少ないかもしれません。nekketsuuu さんの自己回答と合わせて見ても、`file://` がそもそも何であるのか？を問うているのかなと思っていました。

Comment: @cubick さん、ありがとうございます。この疑問を持ったときは「スキームという言葉は知っていたが、検索するときに思いつかず、色々試していてそういえば file スキームという名前があることに気付いた」という状況だったので、「スキームという言葉は知っていたけど忘れていた」状態でした。このことを踏まえつつ、もう少し詳細に質問を書いてみました。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、コメントありがとうございます。ブラウザ制限やオプションなどは考えたことがなかったです。確かに fileスキームに関する個別情報はHITしないですね。NGでしたが個人的に気になって試したことだけ記載しておきます。（役に立たない情報です。）URI「file:///ユーザ名:パスワード@ホスト名/パス」でHTTPと同様の動きをするかIEで確認しましたが”INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND”と表示されました。「ユーザ名:パスワード@ホスト名」自体がホスト名と認識されているようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file://` には [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) という名前があるので、「file URI scheme ほにゃらら」とか「fileスキーム ほにゃらら」とかで検索するとマシになりました。

「file URI ほにゃらら」「file URL ほにゃらら」でもある程度出てくる場合があるのですが、「ほにゃらら」の内容によっては file スキームと関係ない話が出てきてしまいます（例：「file URI 画像」だと画像ファイルのURIについてのページがヒットする）。

Answer (score 2):

記号をアルファベット表記に変えて検索するのがいいかなと思います。

`file colon slash slash`

Comment: この方法はfileスキームそのものについて知りたいときは有効なのですが、fileスキームの詳細な話を調べたいときには役に立ちませんでした。たとえばfileスキームとセキュリティについて調べたいとき「file colon slash slash security」で調べてもノイズが多かったです。

Answer (score 0):

「ファイルURIスキーム」や、「ファイルURL」で検索すると良いと思います。
https://wa3.i-3-i.info/word17110.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme (英語です)

一応解説すると、`file://`はローカルのファイルを開く場合に使います。手元にある画像をブラウザで開いたりするときに便利ですが、`http://`等に比べて、セキュリティ上の制限が多く、ローカルにあるhtmlファイルを`file://`で開くと、HTTPで見る場合と異なることも多いです。あくまでユーザが手元のファイルを確認する用途であり、サーバからユーザのファイルを取得したいときは、フォームを使うなどの別の方法が使われます。

ちなみにURIスキーム自体については、以下がわかりやすいです。
https://wa3.i-3-i.info/word1814.html

蛇足ですが、URIスキームでよく使うのは `http`、`https`、`ftp`などですが、Data URIスキームも実はよく使われます。（Webサイトの表示を高速化する場合など、内部的に使われることが多いです。）
http://www.phenomena.co.jp/blog/2015/02/17/data-uri%E3%81%A8base64%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC%E3%82%92%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと参加してみますと、以下が良さそうです。

`uri rfc file`

最初がURI(RFC3986)の日本語訳の複製のページでした。
[Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): 一般的構文](https://triple-underscore.github.io/rfc-others/RFC3986-ja.html)

2つ目にこれが出てきて、こちらも良さそうな資料に見えます。
[RFC 8089 - The "file" URI Scheme - IETF Tools](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089)

> Abstract
>
> This document provides a more complete specification of the "file" Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) scheme and replaces the very brief definition in Section 3.10 of RFC 1738.
>
> It defines a common syntax that is intended to interoperate across the broad spectrum of existing usages.  At the same time, it notes some other current practices around the use of file URIs.
>
> 要約
>
> このドキュメントは、「ファイル」Uniform Resource Identifier（URI）スキームのより完全な仕様を提供し、RFC 1738のセクション3.10の非常に短い定義を置き換えます。
>
> これは、既存の幅広い用途で相互運用することを目的とした一般的な構文を定義しています。 同時に、ファイルURIの使用に関する他のいくつかの現在の慣行に注意します。